# How to solve requires clause is incompatible

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, c++20, c++-concepts

I am trying to implement a recursive version [`std::iter_value_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iter_t) with C++20 concept so that the base type `T` of nested container like `std::vector<std::vector<...std::vector<T>...>>` can be retrieved. The experimental implementation is as below.

```
template<typename T>
concept is_iterable = requires(T x)
{
    *std::begin(x);
    std::end(x);
};

template<typename T> requires (!is_iterable<T>)
struct recursive_iter_value_t_detail
{
    typedef typename T type;
};

template<typename T> requires (is_iterable<T>)
struct recursive_iter_value_t_detail
{
    typedef typename std::iter_value_t<typename recursive_iter_value_t_detail<T>::type> type;
};

template<typename T>
using recursive_iter_value_t = typename recursive_iter_value_t_detail<T>::type;
```

After trying to compile this code, the only error message `'recursive_iter_value_t_detail': requires clause is incompatible with the declaration` popped up and I am not sure what's `requires clause is incompatible with the declaration` meaning. Is the problem that template struct can't be overloaded like this? Please help me to figure this out.

The expected output of `recursive_iter_value_t<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>` is `int`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lots of things.

First, C++20 already has a concept for iterability: it's called [`std::ranges::range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/range).

Second, since C++11, there is no reason to use `typedef`. Always prefer `using`. The use of `typename` was also invalid. So `using type = T;` rather than `typedef typename T type;` The reason for this is that `using` is much more powerful (you can have alias templates in addition to normal aliases) and that it's a much saner syntax (the name you're introducing is on the left of the `=` rather than... basically anywhere at all).

Third, the way to correctly write a constrained class template partial specialization is that the primary is unconstrained:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct recursive_iter_value_t_detail {
    using type = T;
};
```

and the others are (a) *more constrained than* the primary and (b) have to actually be specializations (see the extra `<T>` in the syntax):

```cpp
template <typename T> requires std::ranges::range<T>
struct recursive_iter_value_t_detail<T> {
    // ...
};
```

This can also be spelled:

```cpp
template <std::ranges::range T>
struct recursive_iter_value_t_detail<T> {
    // ...
};
```

Lastly, your recursive step is backwards. If it's a range, you need to *first* unpack and the range *then* recurse. You're currently first recursing -- but on the same type, so that's infinite recursion. So it should be:

```cpp
using type = recursive_iter_value_t_detail<std::iter_value_t<T>>::type;
```

which you can write shorter as:

```cpp
template <std::ranges::range T>
struct recursive_iter_value_t_detail<T>
    : recursive_iter_value_t_detail<std::iter_value_t<T>>
{ };
```

---

Putting it altogether [[demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/P37EG5):

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct recursive_iter_value_t_detail
{
    using type = T;
};

template <std::ranges::range T>
struct recursive_iter_value_t_detail<T>
    : recursive_iter_value_t_detail<std::iter_value_t<T>>
{ };

template<typename T>
using recursive_iter_value_t = typename recursive_iter_value_t_detail<T>::type;
```

Comment: You should say *why* the `typename` is invalid here (no qualification).